# Display json data in React Native table

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am very new to react native . How do I achieve below ? Is there any table layout I can use to achieve following ? Data is fetched from json file. Any pointer will be appreciated.

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this , i have used in this way and it worked for me.

```
 <ScrollView
          style={styles.ScrollViewDriver}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl refreshing={loading} onRefresh={_onRefresh} />
          }>
          {data.map((c, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.table} key={i + 1}>
              <Text style={styles.tableData11}>{c.date}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.tableData1}>{c.mileage.toFixed(1)}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.tableData1}>
                {(c.duration / 60 / 60).toFixed(1)}
                {' h'}
              </Text>
                <Text style={styles.tableData1S}>
                  {c.scores.speed.score.toFixed(0)}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you give me little bit of explanation of codes ? I am very new to native.